# Want to call php file from javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have php file which includes arrays and I want to call it from javascript file but I don't know the way

I tried this way but gives me unexpected error:

script.js file:

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'line']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineColors);
  function drawLineColors() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'time');
   data.addColumn('number', 'Temperature');
   data.addColumn('number', 'Humidity');

    data.addRows([  

           <?php include 'data.php' ?>

    ]);
```

data.php file :

```
   <?php 
  $servername = "localhost";
 $database = "db";
 $username = "db";
 $password = "124";

 $connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
 if (!$connect) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
$query = 'SELECT * FROM climate';

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);


 ?>

<?php 


        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "['".$row['time']."',".$row['temp'].",".$row['hum']."],";
           }
        }

      ?>
```

Comment: You will need to share how you output your values in data.php

Comment: @Carlos Alves Jorge yes I edited the question with data,php

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want your arrays from 'data.php' file to be pushed into `data.addRows`.

You can use jQuery AJAX, please find the below snippet :

```
$.get('data.php',function(arr, status) {
  console.log("YOUR ARRAY HERE", arr);
})
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: I have array in data.php I want to echo it and show it to `data.addRows` from javascript file

Comment: You can use `json_encode` in `data.php` to get it in your javascript file. 
```
<?php 

        $data = array();
        
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($data, [$row['time'], $row['temp'], $row['hum']]);
          echo "['".$row['time']."',".$row['temp'].",".$row['hum']."],";
           }
        }

        echo json_encode($data);

      ?>
```

Comment: thanks Kunal , But I am still confused how can I call data.php file in my javascript file

Comment: Okay. In your scripts.js file :

`$.get` snippet and in your php file use `json_encode`